# Is it possible to Return a String then Clear it in the Same Method?

Tags: java, synchronized, stringbuffer

Like the tittle says i was wondering if you could lets say make a Getter and in the same method clear it before exiting the method.

Example:

```
public StringBuffer Answer = new StringBuffer();

public synchronized String getAnswer() {
        synchronized(Answer) {
            return Answer.toString();
            // Clear Anwser here?
        }
}
```

**EDIT**

Example 2: With Try and Finaly block:

```
public synchronized String getAnswer() {
        synchronized(Answer) {
            try{
                return Answer.toString();
            }finally{
                Answer.delete(0, Answer.length());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: There are some people answering this question for a _String_ and some answering it for a _StringBuffer_. Please be aware of that, when voting...

Comment: @Bananeweizen: he obviously wants a String returned. There's no ambiguity here.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: Read the question: "...return a String then clear it...". I'm aware of this, but Jim is not.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: Isnt the String buffer the Synchonized one since I have many threads fighting over this variable.

Comment: @Bananeweizen: There is no String variable that he's showing that can be "cleared". String objects themselves are immutable and they can't be changed. It's pretty obvious that he wants to clear the StringBuffer.

Comment: @Alex: are many threads changing the contents of the StringBuffer concurrently?

Comment: What is the reason for these  synchronized blocks?This code lacks synchronization policy and will inevitably end up with a deadlock.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: Yes It is Constantly changing its value, thus is why i want to returning it before clearing it.

Comment: Yes i know that it is what i am trying Right now You just said in a comment bellow Quotes:"hard to say what's wrong with your try/finally without code." Wich is why I Edited it.

Comment: OK. Then the solution is not to use try/finally in this way. You were replying to Martijn which suggested that you were having a problem with his solution, not with some absurd solution.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve by caching the string buffer instance?

Comment: Basicalythis is for a ServerSocket it is the variable were i will store my answer from a other socket. then i will read it with an other thread and decide were it should go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes of course, simply create a temporary variable holding the string you want to return.

```
public StringBuffer answer = new StringBuffer();

public synchronized String getAnswer() {
        synchronized(answer) {
            String returnValue = answer.toString();
            answer.setLength(0); // clear the buffer.
            return returnValue;
        }
}
```

Notice that I changed `Answer` to `answer`. It is a common convention in most programming languages that variables start with a lowercase character.

Also consider using a `StringBuilder`, it is not synchronized which makes it a bit faster than StringBuffer.

Comment: True that sometimes the simple solution is the best! Tried with "Try/finaly block" but it seemed to do the finaly before the return statement.

Comment: @Alex: hard to say what's wrong with your try/finally without code.

Comment: your *answer* lock may escape, it should be a private field

Answer (score -2):

No.  Your method no longer has control, because it's exited at the return.

Comment: shoot, it's trivial to clear the StringBuffer before returning the String. -1. Consider deleting this answer.

Comment: and he's obviously doing it *wrong*. Your job is to show him a *better way*, not to tell him it can't be done.